# Can you attack with a Loading and different weapon in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, action-economy

If a creature has Multiattack (or Extra Attack), can they fire a shot from a weapon with the Loading property (such as a crossbow) and then still get an attack with a different weapon, such as a melee attack?

Comment: Note that Multiattack isn't a generic ability that grants extra attacks; it's a type of action that many monsters have available, and each monster's stat block defines exactly what attacks they can make with their Multiattack action. If the stat block says that a monster's Multiattack lets them make multiple crossbow attacks, or a mix of crossbow and other attacks, that's what it does. If a creature can make crossbow attacks, but their Multiattack ability only lets them make multiple melee attacks, then that's _all_ it does.

Comment: I'm going to try to make the title of this question a little more accurate to the body, for people searching for this or similar questions. If I stray too far from your intent, you can re-edit or roll back my changes.

Comment: I've even seen Multiattack specify *which* weapon it works with. Granted, that was 3rd party content. But essentially it allowed the creature to attack twice with its longsword but not shortsword.

Comment: @Ifusaso That's how all of them read. A bandit captain can (by RAW) only make two scimitar and one dagger attack, not two dagger and one scimitar. Or, if they've lost the scimitar, they can't make two melee dagger attacks.

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes, the loading property doesn’t care about other weapons.

The [loading](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) property says:

> Because of the time required to load this weapon, you can fire only one piece of ammunition from it when you use an action, bonus action, or reaction to fire it, regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.

This restricts only the use of the weapon fired, and doesn’t say anything about other weapons, so if you have more than one attack per Attack action, the other attack(s) can be made with another weapon. Note, the action economy can be tricky. You have to be already holding the other weapon, or you can use your free object interaction to draw it. If you have already used your object interaction this turn for something else, you would not be able to draw a weapon after firing a hand crossbow. [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/59481/62294) gets more into the details of the action economy at work here.